# Из бинарного файла читаются символы переноса

Tags: c++, binary

Делаю упаковщик различных изображений. Но при чтении происходят непонятные действия, связанные с тем, что читаются только первые 3 символа. Дальше различные /x4/x6 и до вероятно завершения строки. Как мне проигнорировать это и прочитать весь файл?

```
std::ifstream file(file_path, std::ios::binary);

if (file)
{
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    char* data = reinterpret_cast<char*>(calloc(size, sizeof(char)));
    if (data == nullptr) return;

    if (!file.read(data, size))
    {
        log("Error reading file: ", file_path);
        free(data);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот тут [практически такой же пример](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/). Только в нем вместо `std::ios::binary` используется `std::ifstream::binary`, а в `seekg()` вместо `std::ios::end` и `std::ios::beg` пишут `file.end` и `file.beg`. А также в качестве результата `tellg()` и второго аргумента `.read()` используют тип `int`, а не `std::streamsize`. / Попробуйте....

Comment: *"Дальше различные /x4/x6"* А почему вы думаете, что это неправильно? Может там правда такие символы?

Comment: @avp когда я читаю бинарный файл, даже std::istreambuf_iterator уже не помогает. Он все равно форматирует в векторе \0 как символ конца строки. И потом я просто не могу воспользоваться им

Comment: @АлексейМорозов, а причем тут ***конец строки***? Далее с содержимым бинарного файла надо работать как с массивом байт. Никаких строковых функций.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблему решил, сохранив специальные символы конца строки в векторе:

```
std::vector<char> buffer((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
```